# Is it possible to detect available mobile operators networks with phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would like to know if its possible to detect all available mobile operators networks in users current area, including some information about them like country Name, country Code with phonegap. If its possible, is there a plugin which will provide such information?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. You could make plugin of Core Telephony framework and use it your project.